What's the grammatical function and meaning of "for" in the sentence below?
Measurements of distance, time, or amount for nouns that we would normally consider countable (and thus plural) end up taking singular verbs.

Details please... What do you mean by "gramatical function"?  Please demonstrate what you think about this question.  Have you used a dictionary?  which one.  The meaning of short simple words like "for" is often explained in words that are more difficult.

Here, for means belonging to: "Here is the front door for this house." Which measurements of distance, time, or amount? The measurements belonging to (for) "nouns that we would normally consider countable". Those end up taking singular verbs.

The "grammatical" role of preposition "for" could be performed by others, including "with". Or "with regard to", which counts as a prepositional phrase. But for reasons which make no sense to me, if we replace "for" or "with" by "regarding" (all of which mean exactly the same, in context), that's not a preposition. That's why I think "naming the parts" like this is usually a pointless exercise. It doesn't reflect reality, which for natural language is all about meaning, not labels.

What is the source of the sentence in the question?

It's from a grammar book named Complete English Grammar Rules.
